# Describing the purpose of a foreign key in the database design

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys, naming-conventions

I'm designing a database using MySQL Workbench and am defining many foreign keys.

I'm curious if there's a best practice for describing the purpose of the relationship.

Currently, all foreign key columns are named %table%_%col%.  I like this as it pretty much tells you how to JOIN the tables.  Although, whilst this describes the link between two tables, it does not describe what the purpose of the relationship is.

For example, a foreign key might indicate a parent or a child relationship, or an owner, or a destination or source.

I could describe the purpose in the name of the index, rather than the column, or a comment for the index.  But, for example, I can't link to the same table twice if I stick with using %table%_%col% for the column name (i.e. one FK might be for who created a resource, and another for who edited it).

So should the column name always describe the purpose and not the link?

Is there a best practice?

Answer (score 0):

Using foreign key only indicates that the referenced table describes a different object, a different concept. The foreign key is simply a pointer and the purpose of using foreign keys is never more than that. This is analoguous to having a pointer type field in a class instead of directly including all the referenced other object's fields. If each row (each entity) has only one parent and one child, it is not necessary to include both directions per entity, but rather devide whether you store a reference to the parent or to the child.

In case of one-to-many relationships (eg. multiple child entities to a single parent) is even more simple because then each child has a reference to its parent, but as compound columns and list types are not defined in SQL, a parent can't contain a list of its children.

Comment: My parent/child was a poor example.  But I'm asking, how to describe the purpose of the relationship in the design, not what a foreign key is.

Comment: You mean why one decides to express an existing relationship between to tables with a foreign key?

Comment: No, no.  This is about naming conventions.  

If you create a FK to the users table, you might name the column "users_id".  That tells us there is a relationship, but its name does not indicate what the purpose of the relationship is.

So when someone unfamiliar with the DB looks at it, they would see there is a relationship, but it may not be obvious what that relationship is for.  But if the col name was "owner", rather than "user_id", they would then know, but that breaks the convention of naming columns using %table%_%col%.

Comment: Sorry then, my bad for not seeing what you meant. Actually as a clean coder, I would go for the "owner". When looking at the DB schema, be it graphical or textual, the FK relationship can be made visible regardless of the key's name.